# django | Unhandled Exception when I should be getting 404 or 500 with fcgi on hostgator

Tags: django, fastcgi

I'm hosting on hostgator and using fcgi for my django app, its a sharedhost so I dont have much choice about flup and fcgi. When Debug = False I get a fcgi Unhandled Exception page instead of a Apache 404 error even though with Debug = True I would be getting a 404 from django/python.

Do I have to catch the python 404 exceptions in the fcgi file or should they just bubble up to Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 produces 500 Internal server error if your DEBUG is False and you do not have templates for 404. Make sure that you have 404.html and 500.html in your templates directory. Also have a look error logs in your admin email.